# Restoring Deleted Front Page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was trying to get rid of the Welcome section on the front page of a WooCommerce site I am building. The site is using the Storefront theme.

I thought the way to do it was to delete the Welcome page from the Pages section of WordPress. However, as soon as I did that, the entire front page of the store is gone and it is back to what seems like a regular WordPress.

Using "Create default WooCommerce pages" feature of WooCommerce does not seem to work as it neither fixes the display of the front page nor creates another Welcome page.

I have several questions. 
1. What went front?
2. How can I fix it, so the store displays again.
3. How can I get rid of the Welcome section on the front page without blasting the entire page off the site?

Any advice is appreciated.

P.S. I should mention that I originally moved the Welcome page to trash. I then saw that it broke the site. In turn, I attempted to restore it, but it didnt fix the issue. I then deleted the page permanently in hopes of recreating it with the WooCommerce functionality. The latter didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the WordPress theme **Customizer**

under **front page** you have the option to choose a page your blog as a front page, here you just need to select the page that you deleted and then restored

this link may be of some use to you... https://atlantisthemes.com/change-storefront-homepage-layout/